# condition that no of days between allotment_date-present date will be > 91 days in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

i have three tables in which one table have allotment_date.in this we have to make a condition that no of days between allotment_date-present date will be > 91 days.please help

Comment: share your query been tried so far, please.

Comment: welcome, what is your sql plateforme? and he definition of your table

Comment: It's unclear to me if you want a condition tor retrieve rows like that or if you are you looking for a check constraint that prevents inserting values like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to ensure that allotment dates cannot be more than 91 days in the past (a bit of a guess - is that what you are asking?) then you would need a trigger:

```
create table demo
( allotment_date date );
```

```sql
create or replace trigger demo_allotment_date_90_day_trg
    before insert or update of allotment_date
    on demo
    for each row
begin
    if :new.allotment_date < sysdate -91 then
        raise_application_error(-20000, 'Allotment date must be within last 91 days');
    end if;
end;
```

This is allowed:

```
insert into demo(allotment_date) values (sysdate);
```

This will fail:

```
insert into demo(allotment_date) values (date '1900-12-25');
```

```
ORA-20000: Allotment date must be within last 91 days
ORA-06512: at "WILLIAM.DEMO_ALLOTMENT_DATE_90_DAY_TRG", line 3
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'WILLIAM.DEMO_ALLOTMENT_DATE_90_DAY_TRG'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below Query for example

SELECT TO_DATE('2000-01-02', 'YYYY-MM-DD') -
       TO_DATE('2000-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS DateDiff
FROM   dual

Comment: the Database is tagged Oracle, not SQL-Server.